# how to count events within several intervals for each factor in R?

Tags: r, loops, datetime, intervals

I am trying to count the number of events that are occurring within each interval and for each of my factor (mystations).

Below is a MWE:

```
library(lubridate)

myintervals <- c(dmy_hms(
"01/01/2000 08:00:00",
"25/02/2000 09:00:00",
"01/03/2000 10:00:00",
"30/04/2000 11:00:00",
"01/05/2000 12:00:00",
"30/06/2000 13:00:00",
"01/07/2000 14:00:00",
"30/08/2000 15:00:00",
"01/09/2000 16:00:00",
"30/10/2000 17:00:00"))

mystations <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","D")

mydata <- data.frame(myintervals,mystations)

           myintervals mystations
 |1  2000-01-01 08:00:00          A
 |2  2000-02-25 09:00:00          B
 |3  2000-03-01 10:00:00          C
 |4  2000-04-30 11:00:00          A
 |5  2000-05-01 12:00:00          B
 |6  2000-06-30 13:00:00          C
 |7  2000-07-01 14:00:00          A
 |8  2000-08-30 15:00:00          B
 |9  2000-09-01 16:00:00          C
 |10 2000-10-30 17:00:00          D
```

Here I am creating the detections

```
date.time <- c(dmy_hms(
"31/12/1999 08:00:00",
"24/02/2000 09:00:00",
"25/02/2000 08:00:00",
"26/02/2000 10:00:00",
"27/02/2000 11:00:00",
"01/03/2000 10:00:00",
"10/03/2000 22:00:00",
"20/03/2000 23:00:00",
"01/04/2000 10:00:00",
"20/04/2000 20:00:00",
"25/04/2000 08:00:00",
"30/04/2000 10:00:00",
"01/05/2000 12:00:00",
"10/05/2000 20:00:00",
"20/05/2000 08:00:00",
"30/06/2000 13:00:00",
"10/07/2000 10:00:00",
"20/07/2000 20:00:00",
"30/08/2000 15:00:00",
"01/09/2000 16:00:00"))

mydetections <- data.frame(date.time=date.time,mystations=mystations)

             date.time mystations
 |1  1999-12-31 08:00:00          A
 |2  2000-02-24 09:00:00          B
 |3  2000-02-25 08:00:00          C
 |4  2000-02-26 10:00:00          A
 |5  2000-02-27 11:00:00          B
 |6  2000-03-01 10:00:00          C
 |7  2000-03-10 22:00:00          A
 |8  2000-03-20 23:00:00          B
 |9  2000-04-01 10:00:00          C
 |10 2000-04-20 20:00:00          D
 |11 2000-04-25 08:00:00          A
 |12 2000-04-30 10:00:00          B
 |13 2000-05-01 12:00:00          C
 |14 2000-05-10 20:00:00          A
 |15 2000-05-20 08:00:00          B
 |16 2000-06-30 13:00:00          C
 |17 2000-07-10 10:00:00          A
 |18 2000-07-20 20:00:00          B
 |19 2000-08-30 15:00:00          C
 |20 2000-09-01 16:00:00          D
```

The origins for each interval are here:

```
myorigins <- data.frame(myintervals=c(
dmy_hms("01/01/1970 00:00:00","01/04/1970 00:00:00","01/08/1970 00:00:00","01/12/1970 00:00:00")),mystations=c(unique(mydata$mystations)))
```

The expected output is this:

```
                                        myintervals mystation value
1  1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC--2000-01-01 08:00:00 UTC         A     1
2  2000-01-01 08:00:00 UTC--2000-04-30 11:00:00 UTC         A     3
3  2000-04-30 11:00:00 UTC--2000-07-01 14:00:00 UTC         A     1
4  1970-04-01 00:00:00 UTC--2000-02-25 09:00:00 UTC         B     1
5  2000-02-25 09:00:00 UTC--2000-05-01 12:00:00 UTC         B     3
6  2000-05-01 12:00:00 UTC--2000-08-30 15:00:00 UTC         B     2
7  1970-08-01 00:00:00 UTC--2000-03-01 10:00:00 UTC         C     2
8  2000-03-01 10:00:00 UTC--2000-06-30 13:00:00 UTC         C     3
9  2000-06-30 13:00:00 UTC--2000-09-01 16:00:00 UTC         C     1
10 1970-12-01 00:00:00 UTC--2000-10-30 17:00:00 UTC         D     1
```

What I was able to achieve so far is this:

```
#line by line
mydata <- add_row(mydata,myorigins)
mydata <- arrange(mydata,mystations,myintervals)
DF <- group_split(mydata,mystations)
Y <- lapply(seq_along(DF), function(x) as.data.frame(DF[[x]]))
names(Y) <- c(unique(mydata$mystations))
list2env(Y, envir = .GlobalEnv)

#splitting the detections
DFD <- group_split(mydetections,mystations)
Z <- lapply(seq_along(DFD), function(x) as.data.frame(DFD[[x]]))
names(Z) <- c(paste(unique(mydata$mystations),"det",sep=""))
list2env(Z, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I believe now is time to "only" construct the intervals for each dataframe like this:

```
Aint <- int_diff(A$myintervals)
```

and "checking" which detection falls in which interval with this:

```
myresA <- Adet$date.time%within%Aint
```

Clearly, I would like to avoid to "manually" construct the intervals for each df As.
As always, I would greatly appreciate any helps or tips for getting the desired output. I apologize for the initial confusion in the post.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better with `mydata <- data.frame(myintervals, mystations)`? Using `cbind`, you're getting a `character` *matrix*, which dumps your POSIXt into number-like strings.

Comment: totally correct @r2evans! I am going to update the code tough is not relevant for solving the question.

Comment: I suspect that your "expected output" is incorrect: you have duplicate rows and many rows missing. Is the result supposed to have 20 rows (i.e., a join on `mydetections`) or 10 rows (on `mydata`)?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what `mydata` is intended to provide ... it isn't used. Should your `subset`-code be referencing `mydata$` internally instead of `mydetetions$`? You do only reference `[1]` through `[10]` ...

Comment: again @r2evans, you were right. I have updated the code and the desired output. Thank you for pointing out these flaws.

Comment: I suggest you find the expected output *manually* and then double check your code. Your `mystations==mydetections$mystations[*]` is placed as the third argument to `subset`, which likely means you're corrupting *columns* there, not selecting *rows*. (It also means that the counts you're calculating are likely incorrect, since `mystations` is not being evaluated. Again, though, count it by hand first, add that to your question, and then we'll deal with fixing the code. It isn't exactly clear to me how the intervals are supposed to operate.

Comment: @r2evans, correct again. I am sorry for the mistakes. The desired output is now correct and calculated manually.

Comment: @stefano Can you clarify your output? For example, station A first interval, is that from 1/1/2000 - 4/30/2000? You have an expected output of 1, but it appears there are 3 events in `mydetection` with station A during that time (2/26/2000, 3/10/2000, 4/25/2000)? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Ben, I am going to update the questions cause I am getting closer to the solution. I apologize for providing a not clear MWE.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options to consider - hope this may be helpful.

Using `tidyverse` you can add your `myorigins` to `mydata`, then after sorting with `arrange` make time intervals (start-end).

You can use `fuzzy_left_join` to add the events table, matching on `mystations` and where the `date.time` falls between the interval `start` and `end`.

Then, after grouping, you can count the number of rows. You will get something close to your result, depending on how you want to handle edge cases.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(lubridate)

bind_rows(mydata, myorigins) %>%
  arrange(myintervals) %>%
  group_by(mystations) %>%
  transmute(start = myintervals, end = lead(myintervals)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(end)) %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(
    mydetections,
    by = c("mystations", "start" = "date.time", "end" = "date.time"),
    match_fun = c(`==`, `<`, `>=`)
  ) %>%
    group_by(start, end, mystations.x) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    arrange(mystations.x)
```

**Output**

```
   start               end                 mystations.x count
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>        <int>
 1 1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 08:00:00 A                1
 2 2000-01-01 08:00:00 2000-04-30 11:00:00 A                3
 3 2000-04-30 11:00:00 2000-07-01 14:00:00 A                1
 4 1970-04-01 00:00:00 2000-02-25 09:00:00 B                1
 5 2000-02-25 09:00:00 2000-05-01 12:00:00 B                3
 6 2000-05-01 12:00:00 2000-08-30 15:00:00 B                2
 7 1970-08-01 00:00:00 2000-03-01 10:00:00 C                2
 8 2000-03-01 10:00:00 2000-06-30 13:00:00 C                3
 9 2000-06-30 13:00:00 2000-09-01 16:00:00 C                1
10 1970-12-01 00:00:00 2000-10-30 17:00:00 D                2
```

---

An alternative to consider is using `data.table` which would be faster. One function that may be helpful here is `foverlaps` to find overlap between the event dates and date ranges.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- rbind(myorigins, mydata)
setDT(dt)

dt[, c("start", "end") := list(myintervals, lead(myintervals)), by = mystations]
dt <- na.omit(dt, "end")

setDT(mydetections)

mydetections[,date.time.copy := copy(date.time)]
setkey(mydetections, mystations, date.time, date.time.copy)

dt_ovlp <- foverlaps(dt, 
                     mydetections, 
                     by.x = c("mystations", "start", "end"),
                     by.y = c("mystations", "date.time", "date.time.copy"))

dt_ovlp[ , .(value = .N), by = c("mystations", "start", "end")][order(mystations, start)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing your solution. It seems perfect to me and surely it was beyond my capacity. I have learned something more!